# CoreDNS custom hosted zone pointing to default dns server

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I'm trying to register a new cluster-wide hosted zone, called `foo-bar.local` which points to the existing dns server. I figured for the host names to be resolved, I would be able to rewrite `myservice.namespace.foo-bar.local` to `myservice.namespace.cluster.svc.local` it would be able to resolve it. So I modified the `coredns-custom` configmap like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns-custom
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  my.server: |
    foo-bar.local:53 {
        errors
        rewrite name suffix .foo-bar.local. .svc.cluster.local.
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
    }
```

In this case I'd expect the `rewrite` rule to happen before the request is forwarded to resolv.conf. I applied the config and deleted the coredns pods and verified it got picked up on the new instances, but when I try to do a `nslookup myservice.namespace.foo-bar.local` from a pod I get a `NXDOMAIN: Name does not resolve` error. Am I missing something? The reason I'm trying to create an "alias" suffix is so I can request TLS certificates matching a specific domain instead of `.svc.cluster.local`. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. this is an AKS cluster, which doesn't seem to support configuring CoreDNS other than via the configmaps.

Answer (score 1):

Your request should go to `myservice.namespace.svc.foo-bar.local`. Not to `myservice.namespace.foo-bar.local`.

Comment: Actually, the `.` at the end wasn't the issue. `rewrite name` isn't enough, there also needs to be a `rewrite answer name`: https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/2347#issuecomment-442934925. That fixed it.